# Mount .VDI file in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, virtualbox

How do I mount a .VDI file in CentOS 7?

I'm trying to load the .vdi hard drive from another VirtualBox instance into another VirtualBox instance.  I want to browse and copy files from the .vdi file.

On the first attempt, I converted the .vdi to raw format:

```
VBoxManage clonehd --format RAW centoOS7Python3p9_tmp-disk1.vdi centoOS7Python3p9_tmp-disk1.img
```

Then tried to mount the image:

```
mount -t xfs -o loop,rw ./centoOS7Python3p9_tmp-disk1.img /mnt
```

I got the error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I tried different variations of the mount but none made progress.  One post said an offset was required but that did not work either.

On the second attempt, I tried qemu-nbd

```
touch /dev/nbd1
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd1 ./centoOS7Python3p9_tmp-disk1.vdi
```

I got the error:

```
nbd.c:nbd_init():L611: Failed to set NBD socket
```

If I try:

```
modprobe nbd max_part=8
```

I got the error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module nbd not found.
```

I read that CentOS has disabled nbd support and I could not figure out how to enable ndb.

On the third attempt, I use guestmount:

```
guestmount -a ./centoOS7Python3p9_tmp-disk1.vdi -i --ro /dev/oldHd
```

I got the error:

```
libguestfs: error: could not create appliance through libvirt.

Try running qemu directly without libvirt using this environment variable:
export LIBGUESTFS_BACKEND=direct

Original error from libvirt: Cannot access backing file '/home/brian/centoOS7Python3p9_tmp-disk1.vdi' of storage file '/tmp/libguestfs9LUDJB/overlay1.qcow2' (as uid:107, gid:107): Permission denied [code=38 int1=13]
```

When I tried "`export LIBGUESTFS_BACKEND=direct`" I get error:

```
guestmount -a ./centoOS7Python3p9_tmp-disk1.vdi -i --ro /dev/oldHd
libguestfs: error: appliance closed the connection unexpectedly.
This usually means the libguestfs appliance crashed.
Do:
  export LIBGUESTFS_DEBUG=1 LIBGUESTFS_TRACE=1
and run the command again.  For further information, read:
  http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-faq.1.html#debugging-libguestfs
You can also run 'libguestfs-test-tool' and post the *complete* output
into a bug report or message to the libguestfs mailing list.
libguestfs: error: guestfs_launch failed.
This usually means the libguestfs appliance failed to start or crashed.
Do:
  export LIBGUESTFS_DEBUG=1 LIBGUESTFS_TRACE=1
and run the command again.  For further information, read:
  http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-faq.1.html#debugging-libguestfs
You can also run 'libguestfs-test-tool' and post the *complete* output
into a bug report or message to the libguestfs mailing list.
```

Comment: Build the nbd module, use qemu-nbd https://gist.github.com/xuhang57/4eef44e4ff080e03be2d833b16142305